# how to execute program which is in my environment variable in a bash script

Tags: bash

I'm just learning bash but the script that I made is running (quite proud of it despite its modest result) except for one little detail:

I wrote a bash script that in the end should execute a program. This program is known in my environment variable, so that when I write the line:

```
my_program -b result.dat
```

The program executes directly with the result file as input (and in batch mode).

I would like to execute this program at the end of my script, so I just have to execute my script, have it make it's calculation, and in the end execute my_program with some options

```
#!/bin/bash

#calculations

my_program result.dat
```

After some searching I found a command that could fit

```
eval my_program

env my_program

source my_program

bash my_program
```

each time the result is the same

```
=> my_program: command not found 

=> my_program: no such file or directory
```

Any way of doing it ?

thank you in advance for your time

**EDIT**

I could write the whole path of my_program ( it works ) but i am looking for a solution that can work on another computer which can have another path.

My idea is that knowing the name of the program, the script can search through the environnement variable and retrieve the path to the program. Can this be done ?

**BEST SOLUTION - by zezollo**

- Finding the program path in every computer to set it is $PATH is taking too much time
- Putting manually "my_program" path in the $PATH variable is recommanded
- Putting manually "my_program" path in the .bashrc is even better for it will stay for each execution

Comment: Have you tried with the whole path of my_program?

Comment: Programs are loaded from directories in the variable `PATH`, and that does not usually include the current directory (for security reasons).  If the program is in your current directory then you can use `./my_program` but it would be better to use the full path name.

Comment: What environment variable are you talking about? What is the name of the environment variable?

Comment: for portability reason, the path can change, and if the "whole path of my_program" can work , i am looking for another solution => editing my question

Comment: but still, thanks a lot for this right answer :)

Comment: You'll have to either specify the path, or have the path of the program written to the other computer's Path variable. How else would the other computer know where to find `my_program`? There's no magic here.

Comment: @JNevill . If we consider that the program is in every computer and the path is written  in the environnement variable BUT the path changes (ex :  from "/home/my_program/" to  "home/all_program/my_program) how can i retrieve it ? knowing the name of the program i guess some kind of search through the PATH variable but i am not confortable enough with bash to say ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Set `$PATH` correctly

The best way to do what you want is to set `$PATH` correctly, e.g. to have the directory containing `my_program` listed in `$PATH`.

To see the content of `$PATH`, just type `echo $PATH` in a console.

To add one or more directories to `$PATH` you can type in a console:

```
$ export PATH=/home/one/more/path/:/yet/another/path/:$PATH
```

but this will work only for your current console session.

You certainly want to have this `$PATH` set the same way everytime you start a new console: then you can add this very same line to the file .bashrc in your own profile.

Of course, you'll have to set `$PATH` on every computer where you want to use your program. But I would go for this solution as it quite belongs to the normal 'installation' process of a program: if you want a program to be called from another script, you'd better tell the other script where is your program. Set `$PATH` is a straightforward way of doing it.

Once `$PATH` is set correctly, your script only need to call directly `my_programm -b my_file`, no need for `eval` or `source` or whatever.

### Use find

Now, say you don't know where is your program and you don't want to set `$PATH` correctly on every computer and the full path of `my_program` is different on each computer (are you sure there's no other solution? There must be a GOOD reason for such a situation, as only have 1 or 2 different possible directories should really be enough and can be easily fixed by setting `$PATH` correctly).

Then of course you can always `find` your program. But it's not really a good solution.

It could be something like:

```
full_path=`find /home/$USER -nowarn -name my_program 2> /dev/null`
```

BUT it means:

- you are sure there won't be several lines of output (that's why I added `-nowarn` and `2> /dev/null` to avoid warnings and to redirect possible output on stderr to /dev/null, but what if my_program exists twice, for instance?). Or you can also filter `find`'s output (only the first line). But well this is really a patch-up job.
- it will be slow, even if you look for my_program only in `/home/$USER`, as in this example. A workaround could be to store the result of this command in a file, and read this file's content (if not empty) in order to run the `find` command only once. But this all would really be a hassle for something you can so easily fix only by setting `$PATH` correctly.

### Finally

Also, do not forget to give my_program the execution rights, otherwise, you won't be able to execute it at all.

Comment: Thank you for that complete answer ! I realised "find was not the good solution considering the extent of the directories on my computer. It would have taken too much time. This is a thorn off my foot, have a good day sir .

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: i can't upvote your answer :( it seems there is a limitation of points before i can upvote)